# Align image vertically and horizontally using flexbox

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

Using `React-Native` I need to centre my `Image` and component `LYDSceneQuestion`:

```
const SplashScreen = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <LYDSceneQuestion text="Welcome to" />

            <Image source={theme.images.logo} style={styles.logo} />
            <NextButton onPress={onNext} />
        </View>
    );
};

export default SplashScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    logo: {
        flex: 1,
        width: 300,
        height: 100,
        resizeMode: 'contain'
    }
});
```

Currently my image aligns to the bottom, how I can I centre it vertically?

Comment: I would look at the second answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flexbox: center horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically)

Comment: Set display: flex; in container

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest a small technique using flex,give your parent view flex one and then arrange the components in separate child views inside it and give them equal flex just like i have done below.

```
 <View style={styles.container,{flex: 1}}>
           <View style={{flex: 2}}>
              <LYDSceneQuestion text="Welcome to" />
           </View>
           <View style={{flex: 2}}>
           <Image source={theme.images.logo} style={styles.logo}/>                
           </View>
          <View style={{flex: 2}}>
             <NextButton onPress={onNext} />
          </View>
        </View>
```

I think if you follow this you can centre it vertically.